# How to properly call an async forEachOf function nested in a waterfall function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I am using the async library in express js and have a problem with using two of the methods properly with callbacks. The variable result3 at the very end of the waterfall consoles out perfectly in its scope. However, in the result function where it needs to be sent to the client, it is a blank array. Thanks in advance.

```
async.waterfall(
  [
    function(callback) {
      someQuery 
      callback(null,result1);
    },

    function(result1, callback) {
      someQuery 
      callback(null,result2);
    },
     function(result2, mainCallback) {
       async.forEachOf(result2, function (result, key, callback) {
         request.query(
          `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = ${result.id};`,
          function(err, recordset) {
            result3 = recordset;
            callback();
          }
        );

       }, function (err) {
         if (err) console.error(err.message);

         mainCallback(null, result3);
       });
    }
  ],
  function(err, result) {

   console.log(result3);
    res.send(
      JSON.stringify({
       result3
      })
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `result3` from within the task it should be the `result` argument for your waterfall callback.

on another note this all would be easier if you switch to promises or async/await. what node version are you using and why are you still using callback pattern when you have so many other options available

this mess with promises could've been written as

`somequery()
  .then(someOtherQuery)
  .then(someotherThing)
  .then(Whatever)
  .catch(your error here)`

or even better with the right version of node

`var result1 = await query1();
  var result2 = await query2(result1);
  var result3 = await query3(result2)
  // do the rest of your stuff`

the point is that you should really reconsider your pattern. it is not known as `pyramid of doom` or `callback hell` for no reason

Comment: This is correct, though the digression to async / await may hide your point: if you change `console.log(result3);` to `console.log(result)` the code should work.

Comment: You are right, async await might be the best option I might have to covert all previous uses as well. Thanks